# Animation of rolling square around div in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to figure out, how to make animation in css+js of square rolling around inside div like in this picture. I'm wonder if it's even possible, because of the rollover to every other side in corners.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: do you want it to be responsive or for a certain width and height?

Comment: I want it to be responsive. For those above, I was really searching about a 2 hours on google found nothing. The animation of rolling square is not hard for me, but the moving around responsive div edge is my main issue.

Comment: then at least paste you code here for the rolling squaer, html markup, basic CSS something that proves your effort ... searching on google it's not like you will found exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

Googling isn't an attempt to try to create a solution. Googling is an attempt to find the solution that someone else has worked hard for.

It looks like you just want someone to do the work for you.

I'm giving you a basic conceptual example. I think I know what you're looking for, but you clearly don't want to work for that goal, so I don't either. This is all you're getting from me until you demonstrate your own efforts.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzQzXe

```
#square {
  position: relative;
  height: 5vmin;
  width: 5vmin;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3vmin;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-name: movesquare;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes movesquare {
  0% {
    margin: 0;
  }
  25% {
    margin: 85% 0 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin: 85% 0 0 85%;
  }
  75% {
    margin: 0 0 0 85%;
  }
  87.5%{
    }
  100% {
    margin: 0;
    transform:rotateZ(1800deg);
  }
}
```